# Highcharts HeatMap issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, highcharts

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas

The above heat map is not plotted in Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I can see it plotted in Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit).

Any easy fix?

[image: This is the issue in Chrome]

Comment: It is working OK to me, Chrome on Windows 7 64bit. I highly doubt that the people at Highcharts would make their demo page not working on Chrome...

Comment: I have copied their code to my local and executing that. Version 65.0.3325.146 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: So, you have **another** problem. It's not the link you provided that it's not plotted, but your **local copy** instead.

Comment: I can't see it plotted on highcharts demo page & in my local. But I can see the graph plotted in Firefox for both demo page and local

Comment: Wait a minute, are you saying that, using Chrome, you cannot see anything in Highcharts demo page?

Comment: Please see the attached image

Comment: In that case email them reporting the issue. There is nothing we could do here at S.O.